# I am unable to convert StringBuilder to string in c# asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, razor

My invoice class has a `StringBuilder` property so that if adjustments are made, the user adds notes as the details of why the adjustment was made.  This property is set to a new empty `StringBuilder` upon creation. Only in edit mode will it get `.Append()` added to. From what I understand, this is more efficient than using `adjustmentNotes += newAdjustmentNotes` every time new notes are added.

My Invoice.cs class is as follows.

```
public class Invoice
{
    [Key]
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Customer))]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public double  InvoiceAmount { get; set; }
    public StringBuilder AdjustmentNotes { get; set; }
    public bool Paid { get; set; }
}
```

When populating my list or details view, I query the database as follows:

```
using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var query = ctx.Invoices
                   .Where(e => e.InvoiceID >= 0)
                   .Select(e => new InvoiceListItem
                                    {
                                         InvoiceID = e.InvoiceID,
                                         CustomerID = e.CustomerID,
                                         InvoiceAmount = e.InvoiceAmount,
                                         Paid = e.Paid,
                                         AdjustmentNotes = e.AdjustmentNotes.ToString()
                                    });
    return query.ToArray();
}
```

Then I get the following error message.

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Values of type 'StringBuilder' can not be converted to string.'

But according to Microsoft documentation, other questions on this forum, and various resources this is the proper way to accomplish this.

I can certainly change it back to a string and use += as needed. There will not be too many notes for this particular property, but can someone please explain what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much!

EDIT:  For clarification, here is my `InvoiceListItem` model class:

```
public class InvoiceListItem
{
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    
    public  List<int> JobIDs { get; set; }
    public double InvoiceAmount { get; set; }

    [UIHint("Bool")]
    public bool Paid { get; set; }
    public string AdjustmentNotes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: in general you don't want stringbuilder in your model, you want string,  you just use stringbuilder to build your string as needed.  It's more of a temporary class to help you efficiently deal with strings.   But fundamentally, it just results in a string

Comment: What happens if you delete the ` AdjustmentNotes = e.AdjustmentNotes.ToString()` line? Does it still throw?

Comment: @Jawad My InvoiceListItem model for AdjustmentNotes is a string.  I did not think it should also be a stringBuilder since I only want to display the messages for this view.  I will not be adding anything to it.  Even in my edit, I will take in a string and just do: AdjustmentNotes.AppendLine(model.AdjustmentNotes);

Comment: @ekke. I can remove that line and I do not get the error.  But then how will I display that info?  Should I go a roundabout way and grab it directly from the database and throw it in a ViewBag??

Comment: I do not think this is the appropriate way to use StringBuilder.  I wanted to be able to easily add new lines of notes to a previous note.  I have decided to just create a new class for notes and invoices can have a list of notes as a property.  The note class will consist of a subject, date, and content.  Thanks everyone

Comment: I'd just use a `List<string>` instead and use `AdjustmentNotes.Join(", ");` to concatenate these together into a single string value, as and when needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core says in the error message :

> I don't know how convert `StringBuilder.ToString()` to target database language.

The solution is to do the conversion after the query :

```
var result = ctx.Invoices
    .Where(e => e.InvoiceID >= 0)
    .ToList() // First execute the query
    .Select( // Second convert Invoice to InvoiceListItem
        e => new InvoiceListItem {
            InvoiceID = e.InvoiceID,
            CustomerID = e.CustomerID,
            InvoiceAmount = e.InvoiceAmount,
            Paid = e.Paid,
            AdjustmentNotes = e.AdjustmentNotes.ToString()
        }
    );
```

If you want limit the returned properties in the query, you can use intermediate type like :

```
var query = ctx.Invoices
    .Where(e => e.InvoiceID >= 0)
    .Select(
        e => new {
            e.InvoiceID,
            e.CustomerID,
            e.InvoiceAmount,
            e.Paid,
            AdjustmentNotes
        }
    );
var result = query.ToList().
    .Select(
        e => new InvoiceListItem {
            InvoiceID = e.InvoiceID,
            CustomerID = e.CustomerID,
            InvoiceAmount = e.InvoiceAmount,
            Paid = e.Paid,
            AdjustmentNotes = e.AdjustmentNotes.ToString()
        }
    );
```

PS :
I found no information about EF Core support `StringBuilder` type, but
your context's model is build with success then EF Core seems to support `StringBuilder` type...

If there is support, it seems very limited (see the error in your question). Maybe you can consider use `String` instead of `StringBuilder` in entity class.